# How i can get User id by student id?

Tags: django, django-models

How i can get the `user id` by using `student id`. I have model named `Student` described below:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
student = Student.objects.first()
# or this
student = Student.objects.get(id=34)
user_id = student.user.id
# or this
user_id = student.user_id
```

And i suggest you to read [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) which answers most of questions like this one.

Comment: Actually it is always better use `_id` it helps you avoid additional query. `student.user_id`

Comment: you are right. updated the answer. thanks @IvanSemochkin